# What are the conditions under which personal data can be sold in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, data-ownership

Say that a business has a list of customers' names, telephone numbers, email addresses and job titles.

This business would like to sell this data to another business, with the aim of the new business using the data to generate sales through emailing and telephoning.

Importantly, the customers in the list have not been made aware that their data may be sold.

Would the sale of such data be compliant with UK laws, e.g. the Data Protection Act?